# width 100% on div with pseudo-elemets :after :before and position absolute

Tags: html, css, width, absolute, pseudo-element

look at this example — http://jsfiddle.net/5esgD/2/

i need to div position absolute with :after and :before peseudo-elements, but background have bug :(

how to fix blue background that it does not overlap with a red background?

```
<div class="button_box">
    <div class="blue_button"></div>
</div>
<br />
<div style="width: 200px; background: green;">i am 200px</div>
```

and css

```css
.button_box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 29px;
    position: relative;
}
.blue_button:after {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
    border-radius: 0 12px 12px 0;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 29px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 12px;
}
.blue_button:before {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
    border-radius: 12px 0 0 12px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 29px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 12px;
}
.blue_button {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 blue;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 29px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/5esgD/3/

If I understand what you want correctly, just add border-radius to `.blue-button`

```
.blue_button {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 blue;

    border-radius: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 29px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yes, u understand correctly. But how about, if background image? look at this http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/580/6649977625.jpg border-radius is bad idea :(

Comment: I assume you are doing the :before and :after because the width of the button can change size...

Can you make that button with pure CSS instead of images?

Comment: yes it need for resize button... but i cant make it without image, because they have texture.